# OS X El Capitan - Cisco Built-in VPN client - split traffic

Tags: network, macos, vpn

On OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), with the Cisco Built-in VPN client, I would like to configure the route table in order to have the following thing :

- subnet traffic 192.168.101.0/24 goes through the VPN
- everything else (196.168.1.0/24 my local network, and all the internet) goes through en0, and not through the VPN

Is there a way to configure it with some tricky route add|change|delete commands?
Moreover is there a way to run this commands every time I connect to the VPN.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part (how to split traffic), I had the solution with the two following code lines

```
sudo route add -net <REMOTE_SUBNET> -iface utun0
sudo route change default <LOCAL_GATEWAY_IP>
```